# Suddenly getting "Debug is supported only for UWP builds" error running WPF application in debug mode

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uwp

I am maintaining a WPF application and have been for some time. About a month ago, I started getting a new error when trying to start the application within Visual Studio in Debug mode: "Debug is supported only for UWP builds." I don't even know what UWP is. The error occurs after attempting to start the application in both Debug or Release mode. It is a multi-project application.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. The WPF application is written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new WPF application and ran it in debug mode and to my surprise, it worked fine. I then went back to my original application and it also ran fine in debug or release mode. So, I guess just creating a new project seemed to work. Weird.

Comment: Reopening the solution worked for me. I think it is cache issue.